# Replacing rows between 2 dataframes in R

Tags: r, join

I have 2 data frames, and I want to write a code that will allow me to check if a row from data frame1 exist in data frame2, and if so then I want to replace the row(s) from data frame1 with the row(s) from data frame2. Here  is an example:

dataframe1:

| name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1 | 1 |
| BB | 1 | 0 |
| CC | 0 | 1 |

dataframe2:

| name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1 | 2 |
| DD | 1 | 3 |
| EE | 4 | 1 |

I want to switch rows between both dataframes, and the outcome will be:

dataframe1:

| name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1 | 2 |
| BB | 1 | 0 |
| CC | 0 | 1 |

To clarify, I want to row AA from dataframe1 to be switched by the row AA dataframe2.

This is what I tried to do:

```
df1[which(df1$name %in% df2$name)[1:nrow(df2)],] <- df2
```

And:

```
df1$name[match(df2$name,df1$name)] <- df2$name
```

Both didn't work unfortunately.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df1
  name A B
1   AA 1 1
2   BB 1 0
3   CC 0 1
df2
  name A B
1   AA 1 2
2   DD 1 3
3   EE 4 1
df2$name %in% df1$name
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
df1[df1$name %in% df2$name, ] = df2[df2$name %in% df1$name, ]
df1
  name A B
1   AA 1 2
2   BB 1 0
3   CC 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `natural_join` is the function you are looking for

```
library(rqdatatable)

dataframe1 <- data.frame(
        name = c('AA', 'BB', 'CC'),
        A = c(1,1,0),
        B = c(1,0,1)
    )

dataframe2 <- data.frame(
    name = c('AA', 'DD', 'EE'),
    A = c(1,1,4),
    B = c(2,3,1)
)

natural_join(dataframe2, dataframe1, by = "name",
             jointype = 'RIGHT')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an *update join*:

```
i <- match(df1$name, df2$name)
j <- which(!is.na(i))
df1[j,] <- df2[i[j],]

df1
#  name A B
#1   AA 1 2
#2   BB 1 0
#3   CC 0 1
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("AA","BB","CC"), A = c(1,1,0), B = c(1,0,1))
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("AA","DD","EE"), A = c(1,1,4), B = c(2,3,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr way using `across`, `left_join` and `coalesce`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df1 <- data.frame(name = c("AA","BB","CC"), A = c(1,1,0), B = c(1,0,1))
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("AA","DD","EE"), A = c(1,1,4), B = c(2,3,1))

df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = 'name') %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('.y'), ~coalesce(., get(gsub('\\.y', '\\.x', cur_column()))),
                .names = "{gsub('.y', '', .col)}"), .keep = 'unused')

#>   name A B
#> 1   AA 1 2
#> 2   BB 1 0
#> 3   CC 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>